# Changing inline style into styled-component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to switch from inline styling to css-in-jsx. I found out about styled-components and was hoping that If I use exactly the same styling features, I would get the same results in both cases. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

For example,

```
<Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div style={{
               display: 'flex',
               flexDirection: 'column',
               alignItems: 'center'
             }}>
      {/* <Wrapper> */}
        <Avatar>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
..................
      {/* </Wrapper> */}
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

when I use this, everything works well.
[image]
However, now I have made this in another file:

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: 'column';
  align-items: center;
`;
```

When I comment out my old `div` and use the `Wrapper`instead of that, I get this:
[image]

Why is this so? If the styling commands are same, why don't I get the same results? Does this mean, I will have to fix all components if I am moving to styled-components?

Also, how can I fix this particular case? :D

Comment: can u check the wapper command wich is wrapping this compoent. parent style can change child style behaviour. Like `display: flex` to `display: block`

Comment: If I change that, the avatar moves up again but is located towards the left of the grid @xdeepakv

Comment: Please add sandbox to reporduce. It is very limited code to debug.

Comment: I kept getting errors in the sandbox but would this help? @xdeepakv I am using material ui's theme more or less. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/sign-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments, a sandbox would be nice. I don't know if it will solve your issue, but usually it's a good practise to specify your styled props as strings without citation delimiters, i.e.

```js
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Comment: I kept getting errors in the sandbox but would this help? I am using material ui's theme more or less. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/sign-in

Comment: Everything within the backticks *is* a string.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, my idea was that styled-components maybe require strict string values when composing the styles–but that appears to not be the case, reading their docs.

Comment: @Jnl actually it's the other way around, you should not specify them as strings, I believe this will solve your issues. So you would replace `'column'` with `column`. Can you confirm this is a fix?

Comment: Yes it worked! Simple careless, mistake! Maybe you can edit your answer too :D